# call function based on foreach loop - PHP

Tags: php, foreach

I am pretty new to PHP and I am looking at a way to recurse an array and go to a specific function depending on the contents of the array.

For example if I have an array with the 3 values of 
'email, name, password '

I would need my code to run each of them functions.

The following code is what I currently have.

```
<?php
$a = $_POST;
/**
*datavalidation
*/
class validation
{
    //  private $output = [];
    public $data = [];

    function __construct($data)
    {
        $this->data= $data;
        $this->begin();
    }

    function begin()
    {

        foreach ($this->data as $key => $value) 
        {
            $this->$key;
        }
        $this->__destruct();
    }

}
```

Comment: What functions are you talking about? How do they relate to the elements of that array?

Comment: Just call the function in the foreach, as you do in the __construct like $this->begin();. Is this what you want or somethink special?

Comment: the function name isn't important, The function will be called the same as the key of the array

Comment: it's better to create a generic function and pass a field parameter, rather than try to call dynamically named functions ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To call a function dynamically, you also need to execute the function, else you call a property, so:

```
foreach ($this->data as $key => $value) 
{
    $this->$key;
}
```

Should be

```
foreach ($this->data as $key => $value) 
{
    $this->$key();
}
```

Comment: In the instance where the $key is = the 'name' will this call up the function name(); ? - thanks.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what is does, for more info: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php#example-160

Comment: One last question, In the instance where Name isn't a function but is a key would this cause an error? and if so how would i ignore this? Would I just use a try catch around this loop?

Comment: You could use http://php.net/manual/en/function.method-exists.php to check if the method exists in the object

Answer (score 1):

```
    foreach ($this->data as $func_name => $values){
        call_user_func($func_name, $values);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function begin() {
    foreach ($this->data as $key => $value) {
       $this->$key();
    }
}
```

Beside this, why are you using the constructor to execute the operation? First create the object and, after the initialitation, call the methods of the object until it is not needed anymore. It will be easier to handle the exceptions and debug the application.

```
$obj= new Validation();
$obj->begin();
or in a single line:
(new Validation())->begin();
```

Note: the second method is available since 5.4 [(reference)](http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php)

Furthermore, it is not necessary to call to the destructor from the ownner object (now you are calling the desctructor in the constructor!! `ctor() -> $this->begin() -> $this->__destruct()` . Someone using your object outside will call the desctructor (on an implicit or explicit way).